# Evaluate keyword density of a given block of text

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use php to pass a keyword phrase to a function and have the function parse a block of text and return the keyword density of the input phrase as a percentage of the total word count of the text block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'lorem ipsum etc';
$keyword = 'lorem ipsum';

$word_count = explode(' ', $text);
$word_count = count($word_count);

$keyword_count = preg_match_all("#{$keyword}#si", $text, $matches);
$keyword_count = count($matches);

$density = $keyword_count / $word_count * 100;

echo number_format($density, 2) . '%';
```

Comment: throws "unedefined function" error on "format_number()" but otherwise, it works! THanks.

Comment: @Scott np, should be number_format - i change the example code. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- Split the input text on spaces to get
  a array of words using `preg_split`.
- Use `count` function to get the total
  number of words.
- Use the `array_count_values` function
  to get the number of time the keyword
  appears.
- Calculate ratio of previous two
  computed values.

You'll have to filter the input text by removing punctuations before you split it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

- http://www.bitrepository.com/word-popularity-script.html

Comment: I found this one very good, It is very well explained. Thanks for sharing. +1

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

- [PHP Keyword Density N-Gram Analysis Algorithm](http://redbeardtechnologies.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/php-keyword-density-n-gram-analysis-algorithm/)