# preg_match_all find chain of words

Tags: php

I'm programming a keywords density tool, but I have some problems with finding a keyword that exists of multiple words.

I used some code of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046074/evaluate-keyword-density-of-a-given-block-of-text) topic on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't fully work.

When I have for example a really large text, scraped from a webpage, it doesn't find more than one keyword. For example:

If I have the text "Hello this is me. Hello this is him. Hello this is her." and my keyword is "Hello this", it doesn't count 'hello this' more than once. But there are 3 instances of 'hello this'.

The code I have:

```
// Count words in the text
$word_count = explode(' ', $text);
$word_count = count($word_count);

// Count matches with the keyword
$keyword_count = preg_match_all("#{$searchterm}#si", $text, $matches);
$keyword_count = count($matches);

// Calculate density 
$density = $keyword_count / $word_count * 100;
```

How can I make my code working for this problem?

Comment: remove `$keyword_count = count($matches);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$keyword_count = count($matches);`

You should calculate count matches, this is in `$matches[0]`. See `var_dump($matches);`

```
// Count matches with the keyword
preg_match_all("#({$searchterm})#si", $text, $matches);
$keyword_count = count($matches[0]); // or use $matches[1], in this case same
```

Comment: preg_match_all returns that count. Why calculate it again?

Comment: @splash58 not again, just once - instead of your calculating. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/Hello this/', 'Hello this is me. Hello this is him. Hello this is her.', $matches);
echo $returnValue; // output = 3
```